# Greedy algorithm in Ruby - any suggestions?

Tags: optimization, ruby

Here is my implementation of the [greedy algorithim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) in Ruby. Do you have any suggestions?

```
class Greedy
  def initialize(unit, total, *coins)
    @total_coins = 0
    @unit = unit
    @total = total
    @currency = coins.sort
    @currency = @currency.reverse
    unless @currency.include?(1)
      @currency.push(1)
    end
  end
  def sort_coins
    @currency.each do |x|
      @pos = @total / x
      @pos = @pos.floor
      @total_coins += @pos
      @total -= x * @pos
      puts "#{@pos}: #{x} #{@unit}"
    end
    puts "#{@total_coins} total coins"
  end
end
```

Comment: It is "a solution using a greedy algorithm", not "the Greedy Algorithm" itself. Greedy algorithm is a concept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@currency` could be renamed `@currencies`, or perhaps better, `@denominations`.  Naming an array in the plural leads to easy naming when iterating, e.g.:

```
@currencies.each do |currency|
```

instead of:

```
@currency.each do |x|
```

The name of method `sort_coins` doesn't match what it's doing.  Whether or not it's sorting, it's also printing.  A better name might be `print_coins`.

`@quotient` might be a better name for `@pos`.

Most of the variables in sort_coins do not need to be member variables: `@pos` and `@total_coins` should lose the `@`.  And, if you decide to make it an argument to `sort_coins` (see below), `@total` as well.

This:

```
@currency = coins.sort
@currency = @currency.reverse
```

Could be this:

```
@currency = coins.sort.reverse
```

The initialization of `@total_coins` needs to move from the constructor to `sort_coins`.  This prevents a bug triggered by calling `sort_coins` more than once.

Consider passing `total` to `sort_coins` rather than to the constructor.  This would allow `sort_coins` to be called on an instance of `Greedy` with a different total each time, and no need to create a new instance of `Greedy` for each.  It would also get the variable's initialization closer to where it is used, making for simpler code.

Consider the constructor argument for the set of coins bing simply `coins` rather than `*coins`, because it makes the calling code easier to understand.  E.g.,

```
Greedy.new('cents', 71, 1, [5, 10, 25, 50]).sort_coins
```

vs.

```
Greedy.new('cents', 71, 1, 5, 10, 25, 50).sort_coins
```

Put a line of white space between methods, and at the top and bottom of the class definition.

---

If all acted upon, these suggestions yield:

```
class Greedy

  def initialize(unit, coins)
    @unit = unit
    @demoninations = coins.sort.reverse
    unless @demoninations.include?(1)
      @demoninations.push(1)
    end
  end

  def print_coins(total)
    total_coins = 0
    @demoninations.each do |demonination|
      quotient = (total / demonination).floor
      total_coins += quotient
      total -= demonination * quotient
      puts "#{quotient}: #{demonination} #{@unit}"
    end
    puts "#{total_coins} total coins"
  end

end

Greedy.new('cents', [1, 5, 10, 25, 50]).print_coins(72)
#=> 1: 50 cents
#=> 0: 25 cents
#=> 2: 10 cents
#=> 0: 5 cents
#=> 2: 1 cents
#=> 5 total coins
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the use of the class and what it will output - it helped me figure out what was going on quickly.